# How to count bike wheel Revolution by 3-axis acceleration

Tags: wheel

I want to use MCU and BMA250E 3-Axis Acceleration for count bike wheel revolution.
and I can read the x-axis datas without vibrate.
[image]

and I want to ask how to analysis sine wave datas

Comment: Your zero point seems to be at around 1015. Every time the signal crosses 1015, that is half of a revolution (180 degrees). So count zero crossings, then divide by two. Or count every two crossings as one revolution. Whatever seems easier to you.

Comment: You want your device to rotate with the wheel?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just count revolutions, you do not need to analyze sine wave.
Just count peaks of that signal.

**UPDATE:**

Of course, with some hysteresis. I take it as natural thing.

I would do max(v(n), v(n-1)) for every sample, until v(n) is like 10% below that current max value, a then start over again for min value.

This is the way I would count high peaks and low peaks. Then it is easy to calculate RPM.

Comment: ... with a little bit of Schmitt trigger or hysteresis to avoid double-counts.

Comment: And with a little reasoning, you could estimate that the amplitude of the acceleration is about 2*9.81m/s/s under most driving conditions, so with a hysteresis of about 1G you should be good to go.